# Fourier series of a complex exponential of a periodic function

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series

There is a well-known relation known as Jacobi-Anger expansion:
$$ e^{ix \sin\theta} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{n}(x)e^{in \theta}, $$

where $J_{n}$ are the Bessel functions of the first kind.

Do you know any other similar expansions for some periodic function $f(t)$ besides sinsuoidal function, such that:

$$ e^{if(t)}=\sum_{k =-\infty}^{\infty} a_k e^{ik \theta}. $$

Comment: Technically, the Jacobi-Anger expansion can be used to produce other such examples. For instance, there exist functions $a_k(x_1,x_2)$ such that $$e^{ix_1 \sin\theta+ix_2 \sin 2\theta}=\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty J_m(x_1)e^{i n\theta}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty J_n(x_2)e^{i 2n\theta}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k(x_1,x_2)e^{i k\theta}.$$ But I'm dubious as to how useful such expansions are. (They go under the name of "generalized Bessel functions" in the literature.)

Comment: There are also Walsh functions and wavelets if you want to escape the evil clutches of sinusoids. Of dubious utility in this context.